# $if f(z) ∈ H(D)$ such that $(f(z))^2$ =$f(z)$ then $f(z) = 0$(TRue?false)

Tags: complex-analysis

let H(D) be the ring of collection  of  all  analytic function on $ D $ under the binary operation pointwise addition and pointwise product of function where D is a open set in $C(complex field) $

Which of the following statement is correct .

1)$  if f(z) ∈ H(D)$ such that    ${(f(z))^{2}}$ = $f(z)$ then $f(z) = 0 $ or$ f(z) =1 $

2). $if f(z) ∈ H(D) $such that    ${(f(z))^{2}} =f(z)$ then f(z)= 1

3) $if f(z) ∈ H(D)$ such that    $(f(z))^2$ =$f(z)$ then $f(z) = 0$

i was using identity theorem  and by identity theorem  option 3  will correct that is $if f(z) ∈ H(D)$ such that    $(f(z))^2$ =$f(z)$ then $f(z) = 0$........i don't know the other option pliz help me  and tell me the solution

Comment: $$f(z)(f((z)-1)=0$$

Comment: ok that mean f(z) = 0 and f(z) =1 ,,,,am i right ?@ Bumblebee

Comment: $0$ or $1.$ Because $f$ cannot take $0$ at some points and one at other points as it is continuous.

Comment: ok that mean option 1 is the only correct option ...Am i right? pliz tell me @Bumblebee

Comment: tell us something about $D$ please

Comment: Let $g(z) = 1$ and $h(z) = 0$ for all $z$. Answer these 4 questions, and you should realize the answer you are after: (1) is $g \in H(D)$? (2) does $g$ satisfy $g(z)^2 = g(z)$? (3) is $h \in H(D)$? (4) does $h$ satisfy $h(z)^2 = h(z)$?